# Paragraph font size being overridden by additional code in my <head> tags. Where does this come from?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I am having trouble adjusting the font size of the excerpt block. When inspecting my page in the dev tools I see the following lines in my header tags. Problem persists with Gutenberg enabled or disabled.

Notice the final line where the paragraph font size is being set...

```
<style id="wp-block-paragraph-inline-css">
.is-small-text{font-size:.875em}.is-regular-text{font-size:1em}.is-large-text{font-size:2.25em}.is-larger-text{font-size:3em}.has-drop-cap:not(:focus):first-letter{float:left;font-size:8.4em;font-style:normal;font-weight:100;line-height:.68;margin:.05em .1em 0 0;text-transform:uppercase}body.rtl .has-drop-cap:not(:focus):first-letter{float:none;margin-left:.1em}p.has-drop-cap.has-background{overflow:hidden}p.has-background{padding:1.25em 2.375em}:where(p.has-text-color:not(.has-link-color)) a{color:inherit}
p{font-size: var(--wp--preset--font-size--medium);}
</style>
```

When I look at the blocks/paragraph/style.css file that is being applied to that block I see the following.

Notice the p style at the bottom isn't there?

```
.is-small-text{font-size:.875em}.is-regular-text{font-size:1em}.is-large-text{font-size:2.25em}.is-larger-text{font-size:3em}.has-drop-cap:not(:focus):first-letter{float:left;font-size:8.4em;font-style:normal;font-weight:100;line-height:.68;margin:.05em .1em 0 0;text-transform:uppercase}body.rtl .has-drop-cap:not(:focus):first-letter{float:none;margin-left:.1em}p.has-drop-cap.has-background{overflow:hidden}p.has-background{padding:1.25em 2.375em}:where(p.has-text-color:not(.has-link-color)) a{color:inherit}
```

So my question is, where is this line coming from?

```
p{font-size: var(--wp--preset--font-size--medium);}
```

I have removed the line in dev tools and this solves the problem, but can't fin the origin of the code?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my own question in the blocks/paragraph/block.json file. Right at the bottom there was an attribute called "__experimentalSelector".

By removing this code my problem was solved and I can now make adjustments to the font size.

Is the fact that I couldnt override this in the FSE a bug or a feature?

```
,
        "__experimentalSelector": "p",
        "__unstablePasteTextInline": true
```

Thanks.